# how to do backface culling using blender python API for rendering degenerated faces

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine

The model can be [downloaded here](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/files/9199916/02691156.zip), which is made and exported in a bad way different from the conventional way. As [the pose said](https://developer.blender.org/T48423), the
normals of the faces seems incorrect.

In meshlab with backface culling mode, the model looks like what I want

[image]

However, when I am trying to render the model with blender python API, the rendered images looks really different from that in meshlab. How can I obtain similar results to the meshlab using blender python API. Appreciate any help!

[image]

---

I have, to some extend, resolved the problem of backface culling by using the experimental importing API in blender v3.4.0

```
bpy.ops.wm.obj_import(filepath=obj, forward_axis='Y', up_axis='Z')
for i, mat in enumerate(bpy.data.materials):
    mat.use_backface_culling = True
```

Another problem is encountered, the diffusion image and the rendered image looks different.

The rendered image,

[image]

The diffuse image,

[image]

Comment: you can set the backface culling for a material using `bpy.data.materials["MaterialName"].use_backface_culling = True`

Comment: Backface culling makes the back sides of faces invisible - this is not something that plays any part in the images you provided. You may be misunderstanding something. Providing more context about what you are doing and your goals might be a good idea.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot with backface culling disabled?

Comment: @Crantisz The screenshot with backface culling disabled will be similar to the rendered image.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys The BlenderProc team has dived into the issue, and found that importing the 3d model with the experimental import way of *.obj in the latest Blender (3.2.1) then enabling backface culling in viewport shading can resolve the problem.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I have tried this but it dose not work in both script and ui app. The BlenderProc team said that I need to import the 3d model in the experimental way since the model is broken. But I have no idea how to import the model in the experimental way with python API in both Blender v3.2.1 and v3.4.0.

Comment: I have added the 3d model in the post and you can try.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie  I have checked the source code of Blender v3.4.0 and successfully rendered the image as I want by calling `bpy.ops.wm.obj_import` and `bpy.data.materials["MaterialName"].use_backface_culling = True`. However, the "DiffCol" output from the render layer, where some colors are turned to almost white, is different from the final output image. Do you know why is that ?

Comment: @Winne, the question is unclear as it is. It is unclear, what you are trying to achieve, what the problem is and what blackface culling has to do with this. I would recommend editing the question and defining the problem in a more specific way if you wish to get meaningful answers. The model in the  .obj file seems to have many issues. I suspect the problems are because of the way it is made and exported, whatever process that is.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys You are right, the reason is that the way how the 3d model was made is different from the conventional way, which makes importing the 3d model in another way possible to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have some white-color faces that cover colored faces. You can easly delete them.

1. Select model, open edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Set face select mode (<kbd>3</kbd>)

[image]

3. Select  white-color material on the material tab, and press select button

[image]

4. you will see, that all white faces has been selected:

[image]

5. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> ⇾ Faces

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response ! The reason may be that the model is with double faces and the backface culling will make the normals of the backface (of white materials) incorrect. since I have thousands of models made in similar way, how can I do in a general way ? Like turning the model to single-sided ?

Comment: I found that this method removes the tail fin as well.