# the color of the rendered diffused image is wrong

Tags: rendering

I am working on the [3d model](https://github.com/DLR-RM/BlenderProc/files/9199916/02691156.zip), which has degenerated faces. I import the model using blender v3.2.1 with the "Wavefront (*.obj) experimental" option, and set all the materials with backface culling.

The rendered combined image looks like this, which is ok

[image]

However, the rendered diffused image looks like this, which is weird

[image]

How can I recover the color of the diffused image ?

Comment: Are the face normals perhaps pointing in the wrong direction? I see in the screenshot that _Backface Culling_ is enabled on the selected material, is that true for the others as well?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I enable backface culling for all the materials. It is weird that why the combined image is ok but the diffused image is so much different.

Comment: Why do you think that Diffuse Color Pass is looking weird? It looks exactly as it has to.

Comment: @YuriTitko thanks for your response. I am new to blender as well as 3d rendering, and what makes me confused is that the body of the plane is almost white. Would you please explain the reason ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: @YuriTitko The _Diffuse Color_ pass is supposed to be looking like the right side of my answer's last image.

Comment: @Winne sorry my bad, now the issue is clear. But you've already have a helpfull answer by Crantisz. You need to delete white faces on top of green ones.

Answer (score 1):

You may face the problem that backface culling doesn't work in passes preview. This issue is so subtle, so I cannot reproduce it. Remove unwanted faces as I suggested in the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/270549/how-to-do-backface-culling-using-blender-python-api-for-rendering-degenerated-fa/270646#270646), and it will solve the problem.

Comment: In my Blender, backface culling works in passes preview.

Answer (score 0):

If you disable *Backface Culling* on one of the white materials, the one named "material_1_24", you can see in *Combined* view that it is covering all the parts where the *Diffuse Color* pass looks incorrect.

[image: white faces]

Go into *Edit Mode* and make sure all faces are deselected with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. Then choose the material "material_1_24" in the *Material Properties* and click the *Select* button beneath the material slots.

[image: selected material faces]

Now that all faces using this material are selected, go into the *3D Viewport* and hit <kbd>X</kbd> > *Delete* > *Faces*.

[image: delete faces]

Since those were double faces, the model is still intact and the correct colors show up, in *Edit Mode*,  *Combined* view as well as in the *Diffuce Color* pass.

[image: correct colors]

The problem here is that the model seems to be created in a software that allows to create two faces from the same vertices. I guess you are using *Import* > *Wavefront (.obj) **(experimental)*** to import the model. If so, you have to check the *Validate Meshes* option. This eliminates double faces sharing their vertices. Or choose the normal *Import* > *Wavefront (.obj)* to import those models.

I guess from the issues here that the software which originally created the model seems to (or a least can) work with single-sided faces, so one face is showing the outside, and another in the same space sharing the same vertices shows the inside. In Blender faces are always double-sided.

Now the problem upon importing them is, when you force Blender to merge these faces with the normal import or the experimental with *Validate Meshes*, suddenly there is one face that has two materials associated with it but can keep only one - which results in the model having some faces showing the correct outside material, some faces showing the other material which was supposed to be inside.

And I don't see an easy way to tell Blender for each face which material to choose, but maybe someone else has a solution.

Comment: thanks for your valuable response ! as you said, the reason is that the model is with double faces and the backface culling will make the normals of the backface (of white materials) incorrect. since I have thousands of models made in similar way, how can I do in a general way ? Like turning the model to single-sided ?

Comment: It's not that you have to make the faces single-sided, faces are always double-sided in Blender. The problem is not of one face being double-sided, it's two faces in the same place - and using the same vertices. That's why you cannot get rid of them by e.g. merging vertices by distance. I have no idea how to automate this process. By the way, I see I made a mistake. The tail fin seems to be gone because there were no doubled faces, it simply had this material on it. So you have to deselect this first before you delete faces.

Comment: I'll make an edit at the end of my answer to explain why this happens and what option do you have on import.